# C++ alternative to sscanf()

Tags: c++, cin, scanf

I have the following function:

```
static void cmd_test(char *s)
 {
    int d = maxdepth;
    sscanf(s, "%*s%d", &d);
    root_search(d);
  }
```

How can I achieve the same output in a C++ way, rather than using `sscanf`?

Answer (score 6):

```
int d = maxdepth;
sscanf(s, "%*s%d", &d);
```

Reads a string (which does not store anywhere) and then reads a decimal integer. Using streams it would be:

```
std::string dont_care;
int d = maxdepth;

std::istringstream stream( s );
stream >> dont_care >> d;
```

Comment: i'M GETTING:                                                                                                                std::istringstream stream' has initializer but incomplete type ERROR

Comment: @user975900: You need to `#include <sstream>`