# Emulating sscanf's %*s with istreamstream

Tags: c++, istringstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ alternative to sscanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883383/c-alternative-to-sscanf)

I have the following line of code

```
sscanf(s, "%*s%d", &d);
```

How would I do this using `istringstream`?

I tried this:

```
istringstream stream(s);
(stream >> d);
```

But it is not correct because of `*s` in `sscanf()`.

Comment: Please share your definitions of `s` and `d`. I am sure "the compiler's understanding" is just fine.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Oh no! AI Compilers! Whatever you do, do **not** use an AI compiler to compile the source for the US nuclear missile launch program! And do not create any program called `Airnet.cpp` or `Skyweb.cpp`, either.

Answer (score 2):

The `%*s` used with `sscanf` basically means to *ignore* a string (any characters up until a whitespace), and then after that you're telling it to read in an integer (`%*s`**`%d`**). The asterisk (`*`) has nothing to do with pointers in this case.

So using `stringstream`s, just emulate the same behaviour; read in a string that you can ignore before you read in the integer.

```
int d;
string dummy;
istringstream stream(s);

stream >> dummy >> d;
```

ie. With the following small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   string s = "abc 123";

   int d;
   string dummy;
   istringstream stream(s);

   stream >> dummy >> d;

   cout << "The value of d is: " << d << ", and we ignored: " << dummy << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

the output will be: `The value of d is: 123, and we ignored: abc`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pointer manipulation in your code.

As [AusCBloke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936274/istringstream-pointers-c-manipulation/7936331#7936331) has said, you need to read the all of the unwanted characters before the `int` into a `std::string`. You also want to ensure that you handle malformed values of `s`, such as those with any integers.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Answer: 42. Some other stuff.";
    int d = 0;

    sscanf(s, "%*s%d", &d);
    assert(42 == d);

    d = 0;

    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string dummy;
    if (iss >> dummy >> d)
    {
        assert(dummy == "Answer:");
        assert(42 == d);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(!"An error occurred and will be handled here");
    }
}
```